# 'Uncaught InvalidValueError' (: setCenter: not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral object)

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm starting to know PHP and JavaScript, mixing them in HTML and using Google Maps API (version 3).

I figured how to 'put' various markers but the console will throw me an error:

> " Uncaught InvalidValueError: setCenter: not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral object  ".

I think it's because the var created in the loop is not exactly the object needed but instead a string, though this confuses me, I don't know if I'm right.

This is my code: 
(By the way, the array I'm looping is an array with an array with an array, here's some of it. It follows the pattern, there are in total 6 'places'):

```
$locations = array(
        array(
            'Location' => array(
                'Title'=>'Place',
                'Description'=>'Some Place',
                'Image'=>'pin1.png',
                'Latitude'=>'20.681775',
                'Longitude'=>'-103.351479'
            )
        ),…
```

(It continues…).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <style type="text/css">
      html { height: 100% }
      body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
      #map-canvas { height: 100% }
    </style>    

        <script type="text/javascript"
          src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?AIzaSyBVfO8LckdOHAot1a8rZW0bmJIoWO2A3os=API_KEY&sensor=true">
        </script>


      <script type="text/javascript">
      function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
          center: (20.68177501, -103.3514794),
          zoom: 15,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
            mapOptions);

        // To add the marker to the map, use the 'map' property
        <?php $i = 0; ?>
        <?php foreach($locations as $key => $value): ?>
                <?php foreach($value as $key => $value): ?>
                    <?php foreach($value as $key => $value): ?>
                        <?php if($key == "Latitude"): ?>
                            <?php $myLatLng = "$value, "; endif;?>
                        <?php if($key == "Longitude"): ?>
                            <?php $myLatLng .="$value"; ?>

        var myLatlng<?php echo $i; ?> = new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $myLatLng; ?>);
        var marker<?php echo $i; ?> = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: (myLatlng<?php echo $i; ?>),
        title:"Hello World!"
        });
        marker<?php echo $i; ?>.setMap(map); 

                            <?php $i++; ?>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
      }
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>


  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"/>
  </body>
</html>
```

And here's a screenshot of that var assigning part:

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is also worth noting that Google Maps v3 doesn't appear to sanitize the data values for setting markers. This seems to have changed in the last few weeks, because previously I was passing in icon height as a string for google's MarkerImage function (it is coming from JSON). But that suddenly broke because it wasn't a "number".

Obviously the solution is to pass in a number, or wrap your data in `parseInt()` or `parseFloat()` so that the API gets a number or float. Google "should" be sanitizing it's data but it isn't.

```
var custom_icon = new google.maps.MarkerImage(
    icon_path,
    new google.maps.Size(
        parseInt(icon_options.width),
        parseInt(icon_options.height)
    ),
    new google.maps.Point(
        parseFloat(icon_options.origin_x),
        parseFloat(icon_options.origin_y)
    ),
    new google.maps.Point(
        parseFloat(icon_options.anchor_x),
        parseFloat(icon_options.anchor_y)
    )
);
```

Answer (score 18):

You are initializing `mapOptions` in wrong way.

Initialize it in following way..

```
var mapOptions = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(20.68177501, -103.3514794),
          zoom: 15,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
```

Instead of...

```
var mapOptions = {
          center: (20.68177501, -103.3514794), //this is not correct
          zoom: 15,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
```

Following is corrected code...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <style type="text/css">
      html { height: 100% }
      body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
      #map-canvas { height: 100% }
    </style>    

        <script type="text/javascript"
          src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?AIzaSyBVfO8LckdOHAot1a8rZW0bmJIoWO2A3os=API_KEY&sensor=true">
        </script>


      <script type="text/javascript">
      function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(20.68177501, -103.3514794),
          zoom: 15,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
            mapOptions);

        // To add the marker to the map, use the 'map' property
        <?php $i = 0; ?>
        <?php foreach($locations as $key => $value): ?>
                <?php foreach($value as $key => $value): ?>
                    <?php foreach($value as $key => $value): ?>
                        <?php if($key == "Latitude"): ?>
                            <?php $myLatLng = "$value, "; endif;?>
                        <?php if($key == "Longitude"): ?>
                            <?php $myLatLng .="$value"; ?>

        var myLatlng<?php echo $i; ?> = new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $myLatLng; ?>);
        var marker<?php echo $i; ?> = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: (myLatlng<?php echo $i; ?>),
        title:"Hello World!"
        });
        marker<?php echo $i; ?>.setMap(map); 

                            <?php $i++; ?>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
      }
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>


  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"/>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -2):

Try deleting the line

```
<script type="application/javascript" src="google_maps/google_maps.js"></script>
```

and keep

```
<script type="application/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=your-api-key"></script>
```

Comment: This will just remove the google maps script, rendering all of his code that refers to the API, broken. I don't see how this would help in any way.